# Cakephp Model: How to use all table_name as singular?

Tags: php, cakephp

I've an existing database with about 37 tables which are in singular name. Now, I've to make a cakephp application which controller name should be singular & table_name already singular. My cakephp version is 2.5.5

I can do this with public $useTable = "table_name" or 
Inflector::rules('plural', array('irregular' => array('table_name' => 'table_name')));

But I think it's not a better solution for such number of tables.

Is there any shortcut so that all Models will find table_name as singular syntax by default?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly!

Comment: just change your database tables into a plural form, then you can use the normal naming convention of CakePHP.

Comment: I've mentioned the cakephp version @ndm

Comment: I've a existing system with the database & now I've to made another application by cakephp using the existing database.
It's not possible to modify the database or table names. @r3mmel

Comment: Sorry, you just need to edit each of your model and add this. public $useTable = 'tablenamewithS'; that is the only solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation would reveal that:

```
public $useTable = 'your_singular';
```

in your models does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've mentioned this way in my question. I think it's not a better solution for such number of tables.

Answer (score 2):

### Use the bake shell

You could simply bake your models, the shell will properly set the `Model::$useTable` property for irregular table names that do not match the default tableized variant of the model name.

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html**

### or AppModel

By default [**models are using the model name to create the table name**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.5/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L679) using [**`Inflector::tabelize()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html#Inflector::tableize).

So one way would be to do something similar, and dynamically set the singularized table name for `$useTable` in the `AppModel` constructor.

Here's an (untested) example that illustrates what I'm talking about

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        if (is_array($id)) {
            extract(array_merge(array('name' => $this->name), $id));
        }
    
        if ($this->name === null) {
            $this->name = (isset($name) ? $name : get_class($this));
        }

        // set underscored model name as table name
        // ex TableName results in table_name
        $this->useTable = Inflector::underscore($this->name);

        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    }
}
```

Comment: its not Actual Baking (its code , not Cooking ),Also Bakery is funny & Wrong name to it. Its called `Generating MVC files automatically`

Comment: Nah, that's not correct, CakePHP installs a low level driver that uses high complex combinatorial protein-folding algorithms that heat up the GPU to oven like temperatures so that it attracts string elements from parallel universes, CakePHP then uses the strings to bake 0 and 1 binary digits on the glowing heatspreaders, and finally assembles the code files from the baked bits, jeez, everybody knows that's why it's called bakery! @jQueryAngryBird